# Direct descendants of Moses today

Tags: moses

I'm just curious to know if there are any direct descendants of Moses today. We know that Cohen is the name for the descendants of Aaron. This is because it seems Moses generation ended with him? Their significance or influence was nothing compared to Aaron.

Comment: This question is off-topic on this site. We deal strictly with the hermeneutical analysis of the text of scripture. Your question is not about scripture.

Answer (score 2):

This question will probably be closed soon since it is not a hermeneutical question. However, you may be interested in this:

Judges 18:30-31 might indicate Moses' line: Jonathan son of Gershom son of Moses/Manasseh. In many Hebrew manuscripts the letter nun (נ) is suspended above the name in question between the first two letters (מ^נ^שה) suggesting the name Manasseh. But other manuscripts as well as the LXX indicate Moses. If the latter reading, then the Shilohite priests appear to have been descendants of Moses. From this priesthood came the chief priest Abiathar who was exiled to Anathoth by King Solomon when he came to power (1 Kgs 2:26-27). Jeremiah appears to have been of this same priesthood (Jer 1:1) and thus potentially a descendant of Moses as well. I am not aware of those who we might be able to trace to Moses after the destruction of the first Jerusalem temple and certainly not after the destruction of the second Jerusalem temple. Today, even tribal distinctions have disappeared from memory among the Jewish people except for Levi.